# how to stop copying a text using Ctrl + c and paste on a text box using Ctrl +v. Specially if it has (..) continious

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, validation, client-side-scripting

I wanted to now how can we control pasted numbers if it contains more than 2 dots..

I am working on a lease project which has large numeric lease.
for e.g   151,321,315    I am getting this on key press

But when I paste integer value from MS word,PowerPoint or Notepad

it comes  like this  15131231....

I want if user try to copy and paste on the text box if dots are more than 2 it will not let him paste the value or give him a alert in javascript user friendly alert message.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: So why don't you just convert the number to be in the correct format on paste?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [onpaste event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp)

```js
var element = document.getElementById('pasteElement');
element.onpaste = function(e) {
  var text;
  if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
    text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
    text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  }
 
var dotCount = (text.match(/\./g) || []).length;

 if (dotCount>1){
  return false; // Prevent the default handler from running.
 }
};
```

```html
 <input type="text" id ="pasteElement"/>
```